# Choose returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, random

```
SELECT
    r.[value] as KnownRandomNumber,
    CHOOSE(r.[value], 5, 15, 16, 17) AS KnownRandomResult,
    CHOOSE(FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1, 5, 15, 16, 17) AS UnknownRandomResult
FROM
    (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1 AS [value]) r
```

Why does the `CHOOSE(FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1, 5, 15, 16, 17)` sometimes return null? Even though using the random number obtained from subquery never returns null?

I'm running this on `Microsoft SQL Server` in SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

Comment: `CHOOSE(x, a, b, c)` is shorthand for `CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN a WHEN x = 2 THEN b WHEN x = 3 THEN c END`, with `x` evaluated individually for each `CASE`. If the expression driving the `CHOOSE` is nondeterministic (which includes `RAND()`, but not a column reference), the results can be anything, including no case matching. The docs are at fault here for not mentioning this at all, but if you fetch an execution plan it's immediately visible.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, this cleared the confusion.

Comment: Actually - choose is short-hand for a simple case expression.  Which would be: CASE X WHEN 1 THEN a WHEN 2 THEN b WHEN 3 THEN c END.  Either way - if no matches found it returns NULL.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem with using rand with choose is that choose is being turned into: when rand() =1 then {a} when rand()=2 then {b} ... and it's generating random number each check... which might be confusing the "choose" function and making it return null sometimes because the function was not made to handle a non-deterministic function as input

Comment: @Jeff: ...but a simple `CASE` expression is *itself* shorthand for the "full" `CASE` expression, which is really all the engine supports. Bottom line, anything involving `CASE` will always end up evaluating the input expression more than once, and it so happens `CHOOSE` is another victim of this policy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of index. And you are asumming that `RAND()` returns the same value for each execution of the same query when NOT. Problem is about the logic here, not the function '`CHOOSE`'

Test and play with this and see the values of every field and how it works:

```
SELECT
    CHOOSE(FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1, 5, 15, 16, 17,'OUT') AS UnknownRandomResult,
    RAND() * 4 as Rand4,
    FLOOR(RAND() * 4)  as Floor4,
    FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1 as Floor4Plus1,
        RAND() * 4 as Rand4_2,
    FLOOR(RAND() * 4)  as Floor4_2,
    FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1 as Floor4Plus1_2
```

More info to read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

UPDATE:

I suggest fix that NULL with some IF NULL default value.